# What is the MyBatis equivalent to the iBatis <isParameterPresent> tag?

Tags: java, xml, ibatis, mybatis

I am porting some old iBatis version 2.? code and am wondering how to replace the `<isParameterPresent>` tag? I have read the [MyBatis user guide](http://mybatis.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/en/MyBatis-3-User-Guide.pdf), and know you can do a `<if test="">` but I do not know how to refer to the the parameter object? Does it have a special name? Is there a different tag to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that there is a special variable called "_parameter". It does not appear in the user guide, but it should be there [according to Jeff Butler](http://mybatis-user.963551.n3.nabble.com/Referring-to-a-parameter-object-td3092941.html). You can then test this variable for null.

Thus it seems the replacement for `<isParameterPresent>` is `<if test="_parameter != null">`.